# Change action-url in firebase authentication templates from code

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently generating email verification links via a cloud function, to send them with postmark. I created a custom frontend inside my web app that is verifies the email via the .applyActionCode() function. Everything works so far, the only problem i have is the action-url.
It uses the standard url that is generated for the firebase project (`https://myniceproject.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action`), but i would like to use my own domain (`https://myowndomain.com/authAction`) for this, that forwards the user to my custom verification component.

I'm aware that you can change the action-url by hand inside the firebase console, but i would like to change this via code so this can be applied to different environments via configs. I already looked into the `actionCodeSettings` parameter ([Email Actions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions)) to see what i could do via those settings. I applied the `url` param with my domain, but that only added the `continueUrl` to the query parameters.

tl;dr I'm looking for a solution to change the action-url from authentication templates to my custom domain from code instead manually in the firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

As I was not able to find a native firebase way of doing this, I had to figure out my own solution. What I'm doing now is, I'm just extracting the query search parameters and building my own custom verification link that I'm sending to the user via Postmark. The Code is pretty basic and looks like this:

```
const firebaseVerificationLink = await admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(userEmail);

const searchParams = Object.fromEntries(new URL(firebaseVerificationLink).searchParams);

const customVerificationLink = `${functions.config().url}/authAction?mode=${searchParams.mode}&oobCode=${searchParams.oobCode}`;
```

Maybe this helps someone else.